# Attempted import error: 'common/configs/fire' does not contain a default export (imported as 'refreshDatabase')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, import, export, craco

I'm using craco to create react app. Here is my tsconfig:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "./src/",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

When I'm trying to export function from my file, I get attempted import error. The thing is it works when I'm just running server locally via `yarn start` but fails on `yarn build`

Here is my files, where I do import/export

```js
// /src/scenes/Auth/sagas/auth.ts
import { signUpUserRoutine, setNewUserRoutine } from 'routines/user';
import { store } from 'store';
import { put, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { toastrError } from 'services/toastrService';
import refreshDatabase from 'common/configs/fire';

// ...other generators

function* signUpUser({ payload }: Routine<any>) {
  try {
    yield call(refreshDatabase);

    const { type } = store.getState().auth;
    yield call(signUp, { ...payload, type });
    yield put(signUpUserRoutine.success());
    yield put(setNewUserRoutine.trigger(true));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(signUpUserRoutine.failure(error));
    yield call(toastrError, error.message);
  }
}

function* watchSignUpUser() {
  yield takeEvery(signUpUserRoutine.TRIGGER, signUpUser);
}

export default function* authSaga() {
  yield all([
    // ...sagas
  ])
};
```

```js
// /src/commong/configs/fire.ts
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';

export const config = {
  // some sensetive data
};

export let fire = firebase.initializeApp(config);
export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
export const facebookProvider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
export const firestore = fire.firestore().collection('users');

const refreshDatabase = async () => {
  await fire.delete();
  fire = firebase.initializeApp(config);
  return fire;
};

export default refreshDatabase;
```

It looks like I've done everything correct and it works fine for me locally, but when I'm doing the build I get the error:
[image]

Any help appreciated!!

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: no, I scraped that idea